Увеличение буфера хранения и отправки данных в UDP сокетах на python
Меня интересует, можно ли увеличить буфер данных в модуле socket, который используется в UDP-протоколе, в Python? По умолчанию его размер составляет всего 65 КБ. Существует ли модуль, аналогичный модулю socket, или есть другие решения этой проблемы?
Я пытался отправлять большие файлы в формате UDP, разбивая их на мелкие фрагменты. Однако этот метод, на мой взгляд, требует слишком много времени.

Больше чем 508 байт лучше не пытаться отправлять

@andreymal это и так понятно но может есть какие то другие способы отправки больших файлов или есть протоколы которые работают быстрее чем udp

Зачем отправлять большие файлы через UDP? Чем TCP не угодил?

@andreymal мне хочется чтобы они отправлялись по udp так как tcp более медленный в этом плане

Когда вы обмажете udp самопальными средствами контроля доставки пакетов, он станет ещё медленнее. Не стоит думать что вы умнее чем создатели tcp

Да и в любом случае непонятно чем вам скорость tcp не угодила - десятки гигабит в секунду он вполне даёт, вам мало что ли?
